# Write java resource in src directory

Tags: java, eclipse, getresource

I am making a (tile)level editor using java and eclipse as IDE. I am using getResourceAsStream to load tilemap. And this code to write map back.

```
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource(FILENAME);
File file = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

It works fine, but the problem, that i have two direcotries bin/ and src/. Directory bin/ will be generated by eclipse. So i want edit files in src dir. Unfortunately getResource() works with bin/ direcoty. Moreover, if i rebuild a project, all changes on map will be deleted. So i just want to edit tilemaps in src/ folder. How can i achieve that?

I would like to avoid hardcoding some absoulte paths.

Comment: The problem is you would like to change the source of your app from the app itself. I don't know if it is allowed.

Comment: @Alepac i suppose it works until i pack my project in jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse starts project with workdir = project dir by default, so src is right under workdir. Use relative path

```
File file = new File("src/fileName");
```

Comment: Yes, this works good. Does it depends on my working dir? The reccomended way to work with resources in java is getResource(), not direct manipulating files.

Comment: 1) Yes it depends on workdir. 2) it's a reasonable requriement that app start from its home 3) what is in src is not a resource, resources are on classpath